# SAPUI5 - extend a sap.ui.controller implementation

Tags: sapui5

I would like to implement a new controller that would redefine some methods from an existing controller.

Let say I have:

**MyForm.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.controller("MyForm", {

    showMyName: function() {
        alert("MyForm.showMyName");
    },

    onSearch: function(oEvent) {
        // Do something...
    },

});
```

I would like a new **MyNewForm** controller that would override the method showMyName but would inherit the onSearch method.
Any ideas how this could achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it works like this:

code of the base controller:

```
sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.extend("MyForm", {
    showMyName: function() {
        alert("MyForm.showMyName");
    },
    //Further functions ....
});
```

code of the MyNewForm controller using the MyForm as base:

```
//require the base first
jQuery.sap.require("MyForm");

//extent the base
MyNewForm.extend("MyForm", {
    onInit : function() {
        this.showMyName(); //alerts
    }
})
```

In this demoapp you see it in action:
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/tdg/index.html?responderOn=true
look for util/Controller.js as base class
and for view/Master.Controller.js as usage of the class.

Best Regards

Comment: This works great, **Thanks**. I had already checked this example but because something I've missed the code didn't work. So, just some pointers for future reference: **1)** The base controller class doesn't end with the sufix .controller.js, it is just a regular .js file; **2)** The base controller cannot be used directly as a controller class for a view.

Comment: This is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

MyForm.extend("MyNewForm", {

Answer (score 0):

By calling method `sap.ui.controller("MyForm", {})`,
the "MyForm" controller is not defined and is never available in execution scope.

Where
`sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.extend("MyForm", {})` defines function and referred by "MyForm", and has extend defined on it.